# populating a DropDownlist in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm learning ASP.NET MVC. I had a small problem when dealing with dropdownlist.

This is what I did in controller

```
List<Int32> myList = new List<Int32>();
var a = (from m in datacontext.services
                 select m.ServiceID);
myList = a.ToList();
ViewData["ServiceID"] = new SelectList((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)
                                a.ToList(), "ServiceID", "ServiceID");
```

In the view

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ServiceID, ViewData["ServiceID"] as SelectList)
```

This results in an error

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]' 
>   to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem]'."

How can this be resolved?

What's the best way to deal with populating dropdownlist with a query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an error in the cast.

To fix you can do this:

```
var a = datacontext.services.Select(arg => new { ServiceID = arg.ServiceID }).ToList();
ViewData["ServiceID"] = new SelectList(a, "ServiceID", "ServiceID");
```

or this:

```
var a = datacontext.services.Select(arg => arg.ServiceID).ToList();
ViewData["ServiceID"] = new SelectList(a);
```

In your code `a` is the list of integers. It cannot be cast into the list of `SelectListItem`.

Side note:
`myList` variable is not used in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your list of `Int32`'s into a List/IEnumerable of `SelectListItem`'s. You are not able to do this as a direct cast (which is what you are trying to do, and what you error represents).

You can adjust your LINQ query to return an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` by changing the select return type.

```
var a = (from m in datacontext.services
                 select new SelectListItem{ Text = m.ServiceID.ToString(), Value = m.ServiceID.ToString() });
```

you can then load it into a `SelectList` via:

```
ViewData["ServiceID"] = new SelectList(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you have a dropdown list you want populated with text items, you can do the following:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var viewModel = new Store();
    var storeTypes = new SelectList(
                        (   
                            from t in _db.StoreTypes
                            select new SelectListItem
                            {
                                Text  = t.StoreTypeName,
                                Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)t.StoreTypeID) //convert int to string (yikes)
                            }
                        )
                        , "Value", "Text");

    ViewData["StoreTypes"] = storeTypes;    
     return View(viewModel);
}
```

View:

```
<div class="class">
    <%: Html.DropDownList("StoreTypeID", (SelectList)ViewData["StoreTypes"]) %>
    <%--<%: Html.DisplayTextFor(model => model.StoreTypeID) %>--%>
</div>
```