# MVC Viewbag correct Result count but displaying only item 1

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

Trying to use a viewbag on a create form (view) to let the user pick an "item" on the dropdown.
The dropdown displays and shows correct number of rows (tested) but only displays the first item for the X number of rows.
https://i.imgur.com/2179GTD.png "Image1"

Code of the view controller below as I didn't find any answers to this.

```
List<SelectListItem> Contracts = (from a in 
db.v_xxx_yyyy_aaaa_contracts.Where(m => m.GroupID.ToString() == 
@group).Distinct().OrderBy(a => a.ContractID).ToList()
                                              select new SelectListItem()
                                              {
                                                  Value = a.ContractID,
                                                  Text = a.ContractID
                                              }).ToList();

ViewBag.ContractID = Contracts;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found for this specific problem is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301271/populating-a-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc)!

Had to bypass the viewmodel with ViewData (SelectList) for it to work as I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
var contracts = db.v_xxx_yyyy_aaaa_contracts.Where(m => m.GroupID.ToString() == @group).Distinct().OrderBy(a => a.ContractID);

ViewBag.ContractID = new SelectList(contracts, "ContractID", "ContractID"); // here second one for display
```

Comment: hi @ashik, thank you for suggesting that approach but unfortunately that is not working either. The problem is not on the ViewBag itself but on the query, on the var "contracts", is returning X instances of item1.Isn't that the way to do a simple:

    Select ContractID from v_xxx_yyyy_aaaa_contracts where groupID = X

Comment: a simple ViewBag.ContractID = new SelectList(db.v_xxx_yyyy_aaaa_contracts.Where(m => m.GroupID == @group), "ContractID","ContractID"); is only showing the first ContractID of a group.. repeating it over the X times that group has a contract associated.